# I got 404 error while running it on tomcat server. I have crated directories properly and there is no problem in deploy descripter

Tags: java

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-apps>

    <servlet>

    <servlet-name> Ajay </servlet-name>
    <servlet-class> Ajay </servlet-class>

    </servlet>


    <servlet-mapping>

        <servlet-name> Ajay </servlet-name>
        <url-pattern> /Ajay </url-pattern>

    </servlet-mapping>
</web-apps>
```

this is my deploy descripter

```
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Ajay extends HttpServlet
{
    public void service(HttpServletRequest req,HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException,IOException
    {
        PrintWriter pw = res.getWriter();
        pw.println("this is a java servlet program");
    }
}
```

this is my java code on servlets

tomcat\webapps\servlet\WEB-INF\classes this is my directory

iam excpecting to print "this is a java servlet program" in browser

Comment: does tomcat provides you a log file ? what else have you tried to get more details on the error ?

Comment: Yes it provided a log file.

Comment: check the log for details of error and also include it in your question